# unbalanced parenthesis error with python regex

Tags: python

I have a python scripts which retrives the data from a log file using the regex, while running the script i am getting an error `sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis`.

Below is the script where i'm trying to user regex.

```
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.10/bin/python
import sys
import re
var1 = ''
var2 = ''
Html_file= open("/home/karn/healthCheck_result.html","w")
html_str = """
<table border=1>
     <tr>
       <th bgcolor=fe9a2e>Hostname</th>
       <th bgcolor=fe9a2e>Service</th>
     </tr>
"""
Html_file.write(html_str)
fh=open(sys.argv[1],"r")
for line in fh:
        pat_match=re.match("^\s+\HostName:\s+(.*?)\.*", line)
        pat_match1=re.match("^\s+(.*?\)Service Status:\s+(.*Not.*?)\.*", line)
        if pat_match:
                Html_file.write("""<TR><TD bgcolor=fe9a2e>""" + pat_match.group(1) + """</TD>\n""")
        elif pat_match1:
                Html_file.write("""<TR><TD><TD>""" + pat_match1.group(2) + """</TD></TD></TR>\n""")
```

> My log file has the below sample data: Where i'm searching the "Not" String and if it gets that then print that entire line Starting with `Service Status`.

```
[analytics1] sudo: /hm/it_script/DC/scripts/mainRun.py
[analytics1] out: sudo password:
[analytics1] out: HostName: analytics1
[analytics1] out: Service Status:  NTP Service is Running On the host analytics1
[analytics1] out: Service Status:  NSCD Service is Not Running On the host analytics1
[analytics1] out: Service Status:  Sendmail Service is Running On the host analytics1
[analytics1] out: Service Status:  Altris Service is Running On the host analytics1
[analytics1] out: Service Status:  Automount Service is Running On the host analytics1
[analytics1] out: Service Status:  Filesystem For Root(/) is more than 90% On the Host analytics1
[analytics1] out: Service Status:  Filesystem For /var is more than 90% On the Host analytics1
```

Could you please advise whats wrong here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
pat_match1=re.match("^\s+(.*?\)Service Status:\s+(.*Not.*?)\.*", line)
```

You have one of you closing parenthesis escaped with a `\` so it isn't interpreted as such.

I think this is a simple typo and should be:

```
pat_match1=re.match("^\s+(.*?)Service Status:\s+(.*Not.*?)\.*", line)
```

Additionally, both your regular expressions start with `^\s+` which means *the beginning of the line followed by at least one whitespace character*. This does not appear to match your data.

You also end both regular expressions with `\.*` which means any number of the character `.` (not any character, as you escaped the `.`) which will still match, but only because 0 occurrences is still a match.

There's also a spurious `\` before the H for Hostname.

Perhaps you meant:

```
pat_match=re.search("HostName:\s+(.*)", line)
pat_match1=re.search("Service Status:\s+(.*Not.*)", line)
```

Since the old group 1 of `pat_match1` did not appear to be used (ie. use group 1 instead of group 2 now)

Note, also, that I've used `search` instead of `match` so that your pattern can match anywhere in the strong, so you don't have to match any preamble.

Comment: SpoonMeiser.... thanks for the typo catch but i'm unable to get the desired data it Just prints the ..header only

`bash-4.1$ more healthCheck_result.html

<table border=1>
     <tr>
       <th bgcolor=fe9a2e>Hostname</th>
       <th bgcolor=fe9a2e>Service</th>
     </tr>
`

Comment: SpoonMeiser,  your answer is correct..

Can we get the Hostname pannelled in the left hand only Once and below that's the Service Status of the Services for that Hostname.
I have the html file but i can't find to attach that here.

Comment: I think that's out of scope for answering here; maybe ask a new question?

Comment: SpoonMeiser, Thanks, I'll ask that separately if needed.

Comment: Just observed that the new regex `pat_match1=re.search("Service Status:\s+(.*Not.*?)\.*", line)` not taking the  
characters after it gets _Not_ String the search. example from the run time:
**Altris Service Not**

Comment: Oh yeah, that was dumb :P `.*?` will match as little as possibble, so if it's the last thing in a regex, it will all match nothing - I'll edit

Comment: The hostname pattern would have had the same problem, fixed also